# MySQL find duplicates based on some matching fields and some not

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a MySQL query of game discs to find some duplicates based on some values being the same and some not.

I need the fields 'name', 'disc', 'platform', 'region' to be the same.
But I also need the field 'version' to be different.

I have already tried a number of queries to do this such as the one below but none seem to work as desired.

```
SELECT *
FROM media.amps_2000_box_a
   INNER JOIN (SELECT *
           FROM   media.amps_2000_box_a
           GROUP  BY name
           HAVING COUNT(name) > 1) dup
       ON media.amps_2000_box_a.name = dup.name and media.amps_2000_box_a.disk = dup.disk and media.amps_2000_box_a.format = dup.format and media.amps_2000_box_a.region = dup.region and media.amps_2000_box_a.version<> dup.version
 order by dup.name;
```

Would anyone be able to help me fix this query?

Thanks in advance.

slick

Comment: What is wrong with this one? I assume it the case of not handling tends correctly this this query does not handle those?  Besides read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) and provide text formatted example data and expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something but the solution seems quite trivial:

```
SELECT   DISTINCT
         amps1.name,
         amps1.disk,
         amps1.platform,
         amps1.region
FROM     media.amps_2000_box_a amps1
JOIN     media.amps_2000_box_a amps2
  ON     amps1.name = amps2.name
 AND     amps1.disk = amps2.disk
 AND     amps1.platform = amps2.platform
 AND     amps1.region = amps2.region
 AND     amps1.version <> amps2.version
ORDER BY amps1.name;
```

Comment: I think that did the trick!  Thanks!  Still a bit new to joins in MySQL myself.